# jquery animate, can't get it to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, modernizr

I'm trying to animate a height property, when hovering, but I can't get it to work.
I am getting into the hover function when hovering, but it just doesn't animate the height.

```
if (!Modernizr.csstransitions) { // Test if CSS transitions are supported
if ($('#belt figure').length) {
    $('#belt figure figcaption').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: '7em;' }, { queue: false, duration: 500 });
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: '3.8em;' }, { queue: false, duration: 500 });
    });
}
```

}

Comment: maybe its the `;` sign in your value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$('#belt figure figcaption').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: '7em' }, { queue: false, duration: 500 });
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: '3.8em' }, { queue: false, duration: 500 });
});
```

withouth the `;`

Answer (score 2):

this is html code for my example

```
<div id="block" style='border:1px solid green;height:50px;width:100px;background-color:#bca;'>Hello!</div>
```

and this jquery for animate div height:

```
$("#block").hover(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    height: "100px"       

  }, 500);

},function(){
    $(this).animate({height: "50px"
  }, 500);
});
```

You can also see example this following linkhttp://jsfiddle.net/jzRPa/29/